# How to use Thymeleaf's #lists.isEmpty with Spring Data's Page interface?

Tags: spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data, thymeleaf

I use jpenren's Thymeleaf Spring Data Dialect: https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect

Following his last advice:

> By default SpringDataDialect search in the request for the attribute
>   "page" or if one attribute of type
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Page exists. To use another model
>   attribute, use sd:page-object="${attrName}"

I do something like this in my Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping("search")
public String search(Model model, @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    Page<User> users = userRepository.findAll(pageable);
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return "user/search";
}
```

and in my `search.html` view, here's an excerpt:

```
    <table class="table">
      <caption class="text-xs-center" th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(users)}">No user found</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Username</th>

            (...)

      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
          <td th:text="${user.name}">Username</td>
```

Unfortunately the `${#lists.isEmpty(users)}` doesn't work. It works on other pages where I do not make use of this `Page<?>`.

So how do I do this test?

Comment: I am not sure I get the connection. You refer to the Spring Data Thymeleaf dialect first but then don't use it. The sample code also shows a different variable used in the list expression, not `users`. Page has a `getContent()` method returning a `List`, so handing `page.content` to the list expression should to do the trick.

Comment: I use the pagination but it brings nothing here because it's just somethink like ``<nav><ul sd:pagination="compact-pager"></ul></nav>``
Also I fixed the code, the correct variable is indeed ``users``.

Comment: As you told, using the getContent() is usefull: I succeeded with ``th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(users.content)}"``.

Comment: And finally I opted for... ``th:unless="${adherents.hasContent()}"``

Comment: Cool, I turned that into an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Thymeleaf's `#lists` really expects a `List` which `Page` clearly is not as it only implements `Iterable`. You can refer to `page.content` for the lists content.

As you're rather checking for the presence (or absence) of content in the first place, you could use `Page.hasContent()` directly, which means that a `th:unless="{adherents.hasContent()}` should do the trick as well.

Comment: Would you mind edit your answer and use ``users`` as variable name? Note that I can't edit my last comment above too... can you?

Comment: Result: `Could not parse as expression: "{posts.hasContent()}"`

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the problem is that `#lists` expects only a `List` object not a `Page` object. There are two methods to solve this:

1. By using the `isEmpty()` method of the `Page` class
2. By converting `Page` to `List`

### The isEmpty() method

The alternative way for `#lists.isEmpty()` method is using the `isEmpty()` method on your `Page` object in thymeleaf.

So you can easily use:

```html
<div th:if="${users.isEmpty()}">
  <span>There are no users</span>
</div>
<div th:unless="${users.isEmpty()}">
  <table>
    (...)
  </table>
</div>
```

### Converting

Or you can just convert your `Page` object to `List` by using the `toList` method as follows and use the usual `#lists.isEmpty()` method to check whether it is empty or not, because you have now a converted list.

```html
<div th:with="convertedList=${#lists.toList(users)}">
    <div th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(convertedList)}">
        <span>There are no users</span>
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(convertedList)}">
        <table>
            (...)
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [Thymeleaf lists Utility Object | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-lists-utility#convert)